# Swap 2 char of a C++ array

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, char, c-strings

I have a problem with memory access. When `i = 0`, Visual Studio throws  an exception with reference to a line as labelled in the following code.

Can't access at `0x00AD8B3B` and `0x00AD8B3B` equals `scr+np-i`

How can I fix the for-loop body so as to fix this issue?

```
int o_strrev(char* scr)
{
  int np = strlen(scr) - 1;
  char tmp;

  if (!scr) return -1;
  if (!*scr) return -1;

  for (int i = 0; i < np / 2; i++)
  {
    tmp = scr[np-i];
    scr[np-i] = scr[i]; # this line
    scr[i] = tmp;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you call this function? What do you pass as parameter?

Comment: Bet you pass a constant string, like string literal, to this functiion.

Comment: And the (!scr) check be before stlen(scr) is called ...

Comment: Is there a reason you do not use of the standard library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @Revolver_Ocelot, you are probably passing a `const char*` from a string literal. Since these are, by definition, constant, you can't modify them in the way you're trying to. You need some way to convert `const char*` into a non constant `char*`. Something along these lines will work for you:

```
string str = "string";
char* cstr = new char[str.length() + 1];
strcpy(cstr, str.c_str());
```

I've compiled your code in g++ using non constant `char*` and it works fine. Just remember to deallocate your `char*` when you're done with it. We don't want memory leaks ;)

Answer (score 1):

I see you are trying to reverse a string.
Might I suggest a simpler way

```
void reverse(char *string_var) 
{
    int length, c;
    char *begin, *end, temp;

    length = strlen(string_var);
    begin  = string_var;
    end    = string_var;

    for (c = 0; c < length - 1; c++)
       end++;

    for (c = 0; c < length/2; c++)
    {        
        temp   = *end;
        *end   = *begin;
        *begin = temp;

        begin++;
        end--;
   }
}
```

Make sure you pass character array of the form

```
char word[64]
```

Or maybe by recursion

```
void reverse(char *x, int begin, int end)
{
   char c;

   if (begin >= end)
      return;

   c = *(x+begin);
   *(x+begin) = *(x+end);
   *(x+end) = c;

   reverse(x, ++begin, --end);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're most likely calling `o_strrev` with a string literal, some thing like:

```
o_strrev("This ain't gonna work!");
```

This will compile with most compilers and at most generate a warning.  Try cranking up your warning level.

Instead, you want to make a dynamic copy of your string on the heap and work with a `char*` pointer to that, something like:

```
string str = "This is gonna work!!"
size_t len = str.size();
char* my_string = new char[len + 1];
strncpy(my_string, str.data(), len)
my_string[len] = '\0';

o_strrev(my_string);

// ...

delete[] my_string;
```

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi Edited answer to be one :)